# Как запретить игроку вращаться(Transform.Rotate)

Tags: c#, unity3d

В общем у меня есть игрок, который вращается с помощью `Transform.Rotate`. Я хочу чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, отключалась возможность вращать его. Я пытался сделать это с помощью `FreezeRotation`, но это не помогло

Для вращения игрока я использую следующую функцию, которая находится в скрипте `AstroManeuver`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AstroManeuver : MonoBehaviour{

    [SerializeField] AstroScript astroScr;

    [Header("Maneuver variables")]
    internal Vector2 mousePos;
    internal float angle;
    internal float astroRot;

    [SerializeField] internal GameObject handRot;
    [SerializeField] internal GameObject firePointRot;

    internal bool right;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        print("Astro Man");
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        astroScr.astroManScr.ClampVelocity();

        if (handRot.transform.eulerAngles.z < 90f || handRot.transform.eulerAngles.z > 270f)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
            handRot.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
            firePointRot.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90);
        }
        else if (handRot.transform.eulerAngles.z > 90f && handRot.transform.eulerAngles.z < 270f)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
            handRot.transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, -1, 1);
            firePointRot.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 90);
        }
    }

    internal void ClampVelocity()
    {
        float x = Mathf.Clamp(astroScr.rb.velocity.x, -astroScr.maxVelocity, astroScr.maxVelocity);
        float y = Mathf.Clamp(astroScr.rb.velocity.y, -astroScr.maxVelocity, astroScr.maxVelocity);

        astroScr.rb.velocity = new Vector2(x, y);
    }

    internal void ThrustForward(float amount)
    {
        Vector2 force = astroScr.astroShootScr.bulletRb.velocity.normalized * amount;

        astroScr.rb.AddForce(force);
    }

    internal void Rotate(Transform t, float amount) //Функция которую я использую для вращения
    {
        t.Rotate(0, 0, amount);
    }
}
```

Далее я вызываю ее в скрипте `AstroInput`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AstroInput : MonoBehaviour{

    [SerializeField] AstroScript astroScr;

    [Header("Input variables")]
    internal Vector2 dir;
    internal Vector2 mousePos;

    private void Start()
    {
        print("Astro Input");
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        dir.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        dir.y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        astroScr.astroManScr.Rotate(transform, dir.x * -astroScr.rotationSpeed);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && (astroScr.canShoot == true))
        {
            astroScr.astroShootScr.Shoot();
            astroScr.astroManScr.ThrustForward(-40f);
        }
    }
}
```

Мои попытки остановить вращение в скрипте `AstroAttract`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class AstroAttract : MonoBehaviour{

    [SerializeField] AstroScript astroScr;

    private bool isTouchingObstacle;
    internal bool cling;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask whatIsObstacle;
    private Vector3 posCur;
    private Quaternion rotCur;

    [SerializeField] internal GameObject arrow;

    private void Start()
    {
        print("Astro Attrac");
        astroScr.rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeRotation;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = new RaycastHit2D();
        hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(-Vector3.up), .7f, whatIsObstacle);
        if (hit.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
        {
            isTouchingObstacle = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isTouchingObstacle = false;
        }


        print(transform);
        rotCur = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, hit.normal);
        posCur = new Vector3(transform.position.x, hit.point.y, transform.position.z);

        if (isTouchingObstacle && (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2")))
        {
            astroScr.rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            astroScr.canShoot = false;
            astroScr.mouseRotationActive = false;
            cling = true;

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, rotCur, 5f);
            astroScr.rb.AddForce(posCur * 20f);
            astroScr.rb.drag = 5f;
            astroScr.rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeRotation; //Вот эта строчка должна по-хорошему останавливать вращение
            arrow.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(0f, -.7f, 0f));
    }
}
```

Порядок вызова скриптов следующий:

1. AstroManeuver
2. AstroInput
3. AstroAttract

Comment: А оно вообще попадает в этот код, вы ставили точку останова в отладчике? Покажите скрипт целиком, потому что пока не понятно, что откуды вы вызываете и где именно эта проверка.

Comment: @aepot, _А оно вообще попадает в этот код_. Не совсем понимаю что. Мой код разделен на несколько файлов, поэтому мне будет трудно показать весь скрипт. Но могу сказать что сначала вызывается скрипт, отвечающий за вращение, а уже потом скрипт, отвечающий за попытку запретить вращение

Comment: Ну вы покажите код так, чтобы можно было понять, что откуда вызывается. _Не совсем понимаю что_ - Может такое быть, что код внутри условия вообще никогда не выполняется. Вы проверили, ставили точку останова?

Comment: @aepot, хорошо, постараюсь. Код внутри условия точно вызывается. Все значения изменяются. Только эти изменения ни к чему не приводят

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `rb.angularVelocity` - если установить `Vector3.Zero` вращение будет остановлено, [документация](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-angularVelocity.html).

Comment: к сожалению это не сработало. При попытке задания вектора, он мне выдал ошибку и сказал что нужно использовать тип float, но даже это не помогло. Несмотря на это я уже нашел решение проблемы. Просто задав дополнительный булевый тип и проверяя его при нажатии кнопок для вращения. Но все равно спасибо

Comment: вы наверняка не правильно применили мой совет) Скорее всего вы посмотрели пример в документации, где сравнивается rb.angularVelocity.magnitude < 5  - а вам нужно было свойству rb.angularVelocity назначить нулевой вектор Vector3.zero.

Comment: я вводил следующим образом
astroScr.rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
и мне выводилась ошибка 
Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "UnityEngine.Vector3" в "float".

Comment: ну я проверил, вот скрин, нет ошибок ничего такого. http://prntscr.com/10a1jr2

Comment: Хмммм, странно. Возможно у нас разные версии